# How to get NSArray Object using NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using NSUserDefaults to save and retrieve NSArray using NSKeyedArchiver & NSKeyedUnarchiver

NSArray contains Array of Dictionary Objects.

```
NSError *error1;

NSData *locationdata1 = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.locationsArr requiringSecureCoding:true error:&error1];

[pref setValue:locationdata1 forKey:@"UserLocationsArr"];

NSData *dictionaryData1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserLocationsArr"];

NSArray *locArr1 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSArray class] fromData:dictionaryData1 error:&error1];


NSLog(@"@@@@ Location Array is:%@",locArr1);
```

But locArr1 is getting nil.

```
Error : error1  NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code:4864
```

I tried with [NSObject class] & [ViewController class] but still it is getting nil

Comment: What is `self.locationsArr`? It's an array of what? Your code seems to implies it's an array of `HomeViewController`, but that's strange to archive a ViewController.. You should put the class of the object instead, no?. And what's the value of `error1`? At each step, you should check it...

Comment: I have added Error code. Please check it @Larme

Comment: It's an array of Dictionaries, but what are the values inside that Dictionary?

Comment: Its just key, value pair @Larme like  
ShiftEndTime = "05:00 PM";
ShiftStartTime = "09:00 AM";

Comment: Why don't you save directly to `NSUserDefault` `self.locationsArr`then? It's fully compatible if your values are like that. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults "Storing Default Objects" part.